# Is this the strongest steel?

Tags: material-science

I found this [link where it described steel with UTS at 5200 MPa (755kpsi)](http://www.matweb.com/search/datasheet.aspx?matguid=638937fc52ca4683bc0c3f18f54f5a24), is this the strongest steel or just a typo because value is seemed to be unreal?

Comment: Note that this is described as a "high vanadium tool steel" produced with some special process. The wikipedia claims that [highspeed tool steels is one of the main uses for vanadium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanadium#Alloys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link does not work for me either, but it is not obvious that this is a typo (http://cartech.ides.com/ImageDisplay.aspx?E=111&IMGURL=%2fCarpenterImages%2fA-ToolandDie%2f23-TS23-MicroMeltA11%2f05_TS23_3Point.gif&IMGTITLE=3-Point+Bend+Test ,http://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=638937fc52ca4683bc0c3f18f54f5a24 ). And it looks like this strength is indeed the highest for an alloy (http://gofygure.hubpages.com/hub/What-is-the-Strongest-Metal-The-Hardest-Metals-Known-to-Man )

Comment: It wasn't a typo, it just had session data in the URL. I fixed it in the question.